# can we use common data provider method for various test cases in selenium? Can i pass the excel path and sheet name to common data provider?

Tags: selenium, testng, dataprovider

I have more than one test case naming as classAtest1, classAtest2,classAtest1 etc
Now i am doing each and every class i have to write data provider method seprately
but i want to write only one data provider method and i can able to use it with all the classes by passing excel, path and sheet name

```
**@DataProvider(name="getData")** // supplying data for a test method.
public Object[][] getData() throws IOException 
{
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("**Z:\\MAANTTIANS\\folder\\Excel Sheets\\QestionBank.xlsx**"); // Your .xlsx file name along with path
        excelWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        // Read sheet inside the workbook by its name
        excelSheet = excelWorkbook.getSheet("**MTFQuestion**"); //Your sheet name
        // Find number of rows in excel file
        System.out.println("First Row Number/index:"+ excelSheet.getFirstRowNum() + " *** Last Row Number/index:"+ excelSheet.getLastRowNum());
        int rowCount = excelSheet.getLastRowNum() - excelSheet.getFirstRowNum()+1;
        int colCount = excelSheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
        System.out.println("Row Count is: " + rowCount+ " *** Column count is: " + colCount);
        Object data[][] = new Object[rowCount-1][colCount];
        for (int rNum = 2; rNum <= rowCount; rNum++) 
        {
            for (int cNum = 0; cNum < colCount; cNum++) 
            {
                data[rNum - 2][cNum] = getCellData("MTFQuestion", cNum, rNum); //Your sheet name

            }
            System.out.println();

        }
        return data; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Thank You Debanjan.. sorry for inconvinence.. i am new here

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can use. 
You can pass `DataProvider` name to each @Test method, TestNG will execute each test case with alphabetic order.